# $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

I want to prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.

We know that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, but how can I apply it to $\det(A-\lambda I)$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just use the fact that $(A-\lambda I)^T = (A^T-\lambda I)$ (since $\lambda I$ is its own transpose). $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for that!!